# Autofiltering for Values Deletes All Rows When There Is No Match

Tags: excel, vba

The partial code below deletes rows that match my criteria when filtering, as it should.

But, there are times when I do not have records that match the criteria, i.e., when "Closed " or Open do not exist in Field 12 (Col L) and all rows on the spreadsheet are deleted (not what I am looking for).

Any suggestions for a fix?

```
Set h = Sheets("For acct mng")
    If h.AutoFilterMode Then h.AutoFilterMode = False
    lr = Columns("A:L").Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    With h.Range("A6:L" & lr)
    
    .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="Closed" & strName & "*", Operator:=xlAnd '<Delete Row If Contains: Closed
    .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).EntireRow.Delete
    .AutoFilter Field:=12

    .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="Open" & strName & "*", Operator:=xlAnd '<Delete Row If Contains: Open
    .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).EntireRow.Delete
    .AutoFilter Field:=12
```

Answer (score 0):

### Delete Criteria Rows

```vb
Sub DeleteCriteriaRows()
    
    Const wsName As String = "For acct mng"
    Const Cols As String = "A:L"
    Const fRow As Long = 6
    Const cField As Long = 12
    Const Crit1 As String = "Open*"
    Const Crit2 As String = "Closed*"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then
        ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    
    Dim frrg As Range: Set frrg = ws.Columns(Cols).Rows(fRow)
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = RefColumns(frrg)
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = rg.Columns(cField)
    crg.AutoFilter 1, Crit1, xlOr, Crit2
    
    If Application.Subtotal(103, crg) > 1 Then ' 103 = COUNTA
        Dim drg As Range: Set drg = crg.Resize(crg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
        drg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End If

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub

Function RefColumns( _
    ByVal FirstRowRange As Range) _
As Range
    If FirstRowRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    With FirstRowRange.Rows(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function ' empty range
        Set RefColumns = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: Is it possible to add delete criteria in another field (Col B), within the structure of this code, or would that be a separate sub performing that function?

Comment: These 6 constants and the workbook (`wb`) could be arguments of the `Sub`. To simplify, If the only difference is the `cField`, you could rewrite the `Sub` like this: `Sub DeleteCriteriaRows (ByVal cField As Long)` and remove the line `Const cField As Long = 12`. Now in another `Sub` you could do (call): `DeleteCriteriaRows 12` in one line, and `DeleteCriteriaRows 2` in the next line. If you also mean to change the criteria, you could do: `Sub DeleteCriteriaRows (ByVal cField As Long, ByVal Crit1 As String, ByVal Crit2 As String)`, remove the appropriate constants, and continue as suggested.